# How to migrate from Three.js REVISION: 67 to REVISION: 73

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Three.js

I read a book [Three.js Essentials](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781783980864.do)

I can not understand why with Three.js REVISION: 67 (which is given in the book) this code http://pastebin.com/c4Fhs9Hr works (correctly)

[image]

but with REVISION: 73

[image]

Tell me please how to fix this problem and why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look different because the shading property of the MeshNormalMaterial was removed in [THIS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/9d72d80f3fb00d8e3532ace349c39eba2a8ff22a#diff-717b15a206ca91fed8cb9df26d53be71) commit.
If you are just following through the tutorials in that book (which had an excellent reviewer :) ) you should not worry about it.